# Кто знает, что хотели сказать разработчики Python своими внутренними функциями?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Читая одну "умную" книжку по python, наткнулся на общеизвестную пасхалку python:

```
>>import this
```

Вывод:

```
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters
Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

Стало интересно, что из себя это всё представляет "внутри".

```
>>dir(this)

['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__','c', 'd', 'i', 's']
```

Немного потыкал функции и наткнулся на это:

```
>>> this.s
```

> "Gur Mra bs Clguba, ol Gvz Crgref\n\nOrnhgvshy vf orggre guna
>   htyl.\nRkcyvpvg vf orggre guna vzcyvpvg.\nFvzcyr vf orggre guna
>   pbzcyrk.\nPbzcyrk vf orggre guna pbzcyvpngrq.\nSyng vf orggre guna
>   arfgrq.\nFcnefr vf orggre guna qrafr.\nErnqnovyvgl pbhagf.\nFcrpvny
>   pnfrf nera'g fcrpvny rabhtu gb oernx gur ehyrf.\nNygubhtu cenpgvpnyvgl
>   orngf chevgl.\nReebef fubhyq arire cnff fvyragyl.\nHayrff rkcyvpvgyl
>   fvyraprq.\nVa gur snpr bs nzovthvgl, ershfr gur grzcgngvba gb
>   thrff.\nGurer fubhyq or bar-- naq cersrenoyl bayl bar --boivbhf jnl gb
>   qb vg.\nNygubhtu gung jnl znl abg or boivbhf ng svefg hayrff lbh'er
>   Qhgpu.\nAbj vf orggre guna arire.\nNygubhtu arire vf bsgra orggre guna
>   *evtug* abj.\nVs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf uneq gb rkcynva, vg'f n onq vqrn.\nVs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf rnfl gb rkcynva, vg znl or n tbbq
>   vqrn.\nAnzrfcnprf ner bar ubaxvat terng vqrn -- yrg'f qb zber bs
>   gubfr!"

Кому интересно - может глянуть другие методы...
Но больше всего заинтересовал этот метод...
Что тут написано, и на каком языке. 
Может, кто знает?

Comment: *Чего тут написано, и на каком языке.* Ровно то что выводится. Тупое шифрование табличной заменой.

Comment: это и есть зашифрованный через `rot13` пассаж выше... Подробности на enSO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855758/what-is-the-source-code-of-the-this-module-doing

Comment: И это не пасхалка.

Comment: @strawdog Понятно, что это руководство разработчика :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, нет, это `Zen of Python`, согласно PEP 20: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Текст закодирован [ROT-13](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13)

Расшифровать можно так:

```
s = """Gur Mra bs Clguba, ol Gvz Crgref

Ornhgvshy vf orggre guna htyl.
Rkcyvpvg vf orggre guna vzcyvpvg.
Fvzcyr vf orggre guna pbzcyrk.
Pbzcyrk vf orggre guna pbzcyvpngrq.
Syng vf orggre guna arfgrq.
Fcnefr vf orggre guna qrafr.
Ernqnovyvgl pbhagf.
Fcrpvny pnfrf nera'g fcrpvny rabhtu gb oernx gur ehyrf.
Nygubhtu cenpgvpnyvgl orngf chevgl.
Reebef fubhyq arire cnff fvyragyl.
Hayrff rkcyvpvgyl fvyraprq.
Va gur snpr bs nzovthvgl, ershfr gur grzcgngvba gb thrff.
Gurer fubhyq or bar-- naq cersrenoyl bayl bar --boivbhf jnl gb qb vg.
Nygubhtu gung jnl znl abg or boivbhf ng svefg hayrff lbh'er Qhgpu.
Abj vf orggre guna arire.
Nygubhtu arire vf bsgra orggre guna *evtug* abj.
Vs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf uneq gb rkcynva, vg'f n onq vqrn.
Vs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf rnfl gb rkcynva, vg znl or n tbbq vqrn.
Anzrfcnprf ner bar ubaxvat terng vqrn -- yrg'f qb zber bs gubfr!"""

d = {}
for c in (65, 97):
    for i in range(26):
        d[chr(i + c)] = chr((i + 13) % 26 + c)

print("".join([d.get(c, c) for c in s]))
```

Или так:

```
import codecs;
print(codecs.decode(s, "rot-13"))
```

Comment: Вспомнил про `codecs` и написал про него в ответе и замечаю, что у вас тоже есть :) Это второе попадание мыслей из двух, хех :)

Answer (score 4):

На английском и написано. Зашифрован первый текст через шифр Цезаря со сдвигом 13.

Answer (score 3):

Если откроете `import this`, то увидите, что `s` зашифрованно, а переменные `s`, `i`, `d` используются в алгоритме расшифровки:

```
s = """Gur Mra bs Clguba, ol Gvz Crgref

Ornhgvshy vf orggre guna htyl.
Rkcyvpvg vf orggre guna vzcyvpvg.
Fvzcyr vf orggre guna pbzcyrk.
Pbzcyrk vf orggre guna pbzcyvpngrq.
Syng vf orggre guna arfgrq.
Fcnefr vf orggre guna qrafr.
Ernqnovyvgl pbhagf.
Fcrpvny pnfrf nera'g fcrpvny rabhtu gb oernx gur ehyrf.
Nygubhtu cenpgvpnyvgl orngf chevgl.
Reebef fubhyq arire cnff fvyragyl.
Hayrff rkcyvpvgyl fvyraprq.
Va gur snpr bs nzovthvgl, ershfr gur grzcgngvba gb thrff.
Gurer fubhyq or bar-- naq cersrenoyl bayl bar --boivbhf jnl gb qb vg.
Nygubhtu gung jnl znl abg or boivbhf ng svefg hayrff lbh'er Qhgpu.
Abj vf orggre guna arire.
Nygubhtu arire vf bsgra orggre guna *evtug* abj.
Vs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf uneq gb rkcynva, vg'f n onq vqrn.
Vs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf rnfl gb rkcynva, vg znl or n tbbq vqrn.
Anzrfcnprf ner bar ubaxvat terng vqrn -- yrg'f qb zber bs gubfr!"""

d = {}
for c in (65, 97):
    for i in range(26):
        d[chr(i+c)] = chr((i+13) % 26 + c)

print("".join([d.get(c, c) for c in s]))
```

А `13` с `% 26` это `rot13` или шифр Цезаря с сдвигом на 13.

`65` и `97` это коды `a` и `A`, а т.к. все буквы английского алфавита имеют последовательные коды, `65` -- `a`, `66` -- `b`, и т.д., то в `d` будет сформированы значения: `буквы` = `буква со сдвигом на 13`.

А после в `print("".join([d.get(c, c) for c in s]))` через проход по всем символам будет сформирована новая строка с заменами. а если буквы в словаре нет, то вернется как есть.

---

Кст, есть и другой-встроенный способ получения строки в `ROT13`:

```
...

import codecs
print(codecs.encode(s, 'rot13'))

# The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters
# 
# Beautiful is better than ugly.
# Explicit is better than implicit.
# Simple is better than complex.
# ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Это шутка на «Дзен Python» , код написан таким образом, что нарушает все предложения, перечисленные там.

```
s = """Gur Mra bs Clguba, ol Gvz Crgref

Ornhgvshy vf orggre guna htyl.
Rkcyvpvg vf orggre guna vzcyvpvg.
Fvzcyr vf orggre guna pbzcyrk.
Pbzcyrk vf orggre guna pbzcyvpngrq.
Syng vf orggre guna arfgrq.
Fcnefr vf orggre guna qrafr.
Ernqnovyvgl pbhagf.
Fcrpvny pnfrf nera'g fcrpvny rabhtu gb oernx gur ehyrf.
Nygubhtu cenpgvpnyvgl orngf chevgl.
Reebef fubhyq arire cnff fvyragyl.
Hayrff rkcyvpvgyl fvyraprq.
Va gur snpr bs nzovthvgl, ershfr gur grzcgngvba gb thrff.
Gurer fubhyq or bar-- naq cersrenoyl bayl bar --boivbhf jnl gb qb vg.
Nygubhtu gung jnl znl abg or boivbhf ng svefg hayrff lbh'er Qhgpu.
Abj vf orggre guna arire.
Nygubhtu arire vf bsgra orggre guna *evtug* abj.
Vs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf uneq gb rkcynva, vg'f n onq vqrn.
Vs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf rnfl gb rkcynva, vg znl or n tbbq vqrn.
Anzrfcnprf ner bar ubaxvat terng vqrn -- yrg'f qb zber bs gubfr!"""

d = {}
for c in (65, 97):
    for i in range(26):
        d[chr(i+c)] = chr((i+13) % 26 + c)

print("".join([d.get(c, c) for c in s]))
```

Это называется кодировкой [rot13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) :

```
d = {}
for c in (65, 97):
    for i in range(26):
        d[chr(i+c)] = chr((i+13) % 26 + c)
```

Создает таблицу перевода как для заглавных (это то, что для 65), так и для строчных (это то, что для 97) символов.

```
print "".join([d.get(c, c) for c in s])
```

Печатает переведенную строку.